# cannot translate a equation into python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, math

This is the equation that I am supposed to translate into code.

[image]

[image: The output that I want to achieve]

import math

def main():

```
x = 90
n= 0
sumk = 0
sumk1 = 0

while True:


    k = ((-1)**n/math.factorial(2*n+1)*float(math.radians(x))**(2*n+1))  
    k1 = (-1)**(n+1)/math.factorial(2*(n+1)+1)*float(math.radians(x))**(2*(n+1)+1)
    sumk1 = sumk + k1

    diff = abs(sumk - sumk1)
    print("k = {:d}, diff = {:.13f}, sin({:.1f}) = {:.13f}".format(n,diff,x,k))
    n = n + 1
    if diff < 10**-12:
        break
print("End Program")
```

main()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show your code, and as much as possible of your problem, in text rather than as a graphic. That allows us to copy-and-paste into out editors and test your code. It all allows others to find your question by a web search.

Comment: Also, do you want the left-hand side of the inequality to be completely written in code, or would a simplification be acceptable? There is an easy simplification. Do you want that inequality in code, or do you want code that results in the output you show? These are not at all the same thing. Finally, what is wrong with the code you show?

Comment: Sorry, I must have accidentally deleted the questions. I am trying to translate this maths equation into python code. After I have completed my program. I can only seem to get the first result correct based on the 2nd image(desired output) and can be seen from my code(3rd image). I required assistance to help me understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I required the left-hand side to be translated into code.

Comment: You'd do better posting the code instead of a screen shot.  I can't read that small print against that dark background.

Comment: Compute two sums, take the difference, and compare the delta to a tolerance.  Quite straightforward - what's the problem?  You don't even have to compute the sums - just term for k+1.  You can calculate that difference for k = 0, 1, 2,....

Answer (score 1):

The first sum = `t(0) + t(1)  ... + t(k)`

The second sum = `t(0) + t(1) + ... + t(k) + t(k+1)`

Should be easy to see that the difference is just `t(k+1)`.

You can plot as a function of x and k to see how terms change in magnitude as you add more.